# How to read netcdf data from minio s3 server by xarray?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, remote-access, python-xarray, minio

This is my code:

```
storage_option = {'endpoint_url': 'url', 'key'='', 'secret'=''}
data_obj: xr.Dataset = xr.open_dataset(obj, chunks='auto', backend_kwargs={'remote_protocol':'s3', 'remote_options':storage_option})
```

And it crashed with:
`TypeError: NetCDF4BackendEntrypoint.open_dataset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'remote_protocol'`

My version of xarray is 2024.2.0.

So what's the correct method to read data from minio server?